# Converting Integer (Day Count) X Axis to Months

Tags: python, matplotlib

With matplotlib, given a graph that uses integers representing days on the x axis, like this one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random as nprnd

items = []
items[0] = nprnd.randint(1000, size=470)

y_data = np.row_stack((items[0]))
x_data = np.arange(470)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax1.fill_between(x_data, 0, items[0], color="#0026cf", alpha=1)

plt.show()
```

How can I convert the 470 days giving a start date to display a timestamp on the x axis?

For example, give the graph a start date of January 1, 2000 - where 31 appears on the graph now, February 2000 would appear, on x value 58, March 2000 would appear, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, you want to display the date represented by `some_start_date + 470 days`?  Could you explain more what the end result should look like?

Comment: @farmerjoe Updated the end of the post with an example - does that clear it up?

Comment: Perfect! Much clearer to me now, ill get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html) to produce [labels for the x-axis *ticks*](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks). You can choose your own format with the strftime() method.

#### Create a date object for 01/01/2000 and a timedelta object for one day.

```
import datetime
start = datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
oneday = datetime.timedelta(1)
print start.strftime('%b %d %Y')
# 'Jan 01 2000'
print start.isoformat()
# '2000-01-01'
print start + oneday
# 2000-01-02
print start + 30*oneday
# 2000-01-31
```

#### Make a list of string dates.

```
labels = [date.isoformat() for date in (start + oneday*i for i in xrange(0,470))]
print labels[0]
# 2000-01-01
print labels[1]
# 2000-01-02
print labels[31]
# 2000-02-01
print labels[-1]
# 2001-04-14
```

Trying to get all 470 labels is problematic - there really isn't enough space when you look at the whole dataset.  I was having a few problems with your example so I modified it a bit.

#### Add the labels to the x axis *ticks*

```
import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as nprnd

y_data = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size = 470)
##y_data = np.row_stack((items[0]))
x_data = np.arange(470)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax1.fill_between(x_data, 0, y_data, color="#0026cf", alpha=1)

###### date labels
start = datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
oneday = datetime.timedelta(1)
labels = [date.isoformat() for date in (start + oneday*i for i in xrange(0,470))]
plt.xticks(x_data, labels, rotation='vertical')

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Zoomed in to a couple of weeks on the x-axis:
[image: x-axis zoom]

Using *weekly* datestamps is a bit more reasonable .. a couple of line changes

```
labels = [date.isoformat() for date in (start + oneday*i for i in xrange(0,470))]
labels = labels[::7]
plt.xticks(x_data[::7], labels, rotation='vertical')
```

[image: weekly date stamps]